# How can I use the value of a variable inside of an if statement, outside of the if statement?

Tags: c++, variables, if-statement, visual-c++-2008

My code is like a cash register where product codes are entered and they are billed and a receipt is printed. When I execute my program, the prices do not seem to display nor add up on the receipt. Is it because my priceA, priceB, etc. and the calculations of the prices are inside if statements? If so, how can i use the variable values inside of the if statement, outside of it?

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>



int main ()
{
    using namespace std;


  cout << "Welcome to SM Supermarket!\n";
  int code = 0;

  string product[10];
  product[0] = "Hagen Daaz";
  product[1] = "Bounty Tissue";
  product[2] = "Chips Ahoy Cookies";
  product[3] = "Tide Laundry Detergent";
  product[4] = "Lays Original Chips";
  product[5] = "Sunny D Orange Juice";
  product[6] = "Organic Bananas";
  product[7] = "Oreo Cookies";
  product[8] = "Red Delicious Apples";
  product[9] = "Extra Cheesy Kraft Dinner";

   int priceA = 0, priceB = 0, priceC = 0, priceD = 0, priceE = 0, priceF = 0, priceG = 0, priceH = 0, priceI = 0, priceJ = 0;

 // while (code != 000){
  cout << "Please enter the barcode of your item\n";


  cin >> code;

  int amount = 0;
  cout << "How many do you want to purchase?\n";


  cin >> amount;



      if (code == 0123){
      priceA = 7 * amount;
     printf("%s\n",product[0].c_str());
      }

  else if (code == 0124){
      priceB = 10 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[1].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0125){
      priceC = 3 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[2].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0126){
      priceD = 6 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[3].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0127){
      priceE = 2 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[4].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0133){
      priceF = 3 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[5].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0134){
      priceG = 5 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[6].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0130){
     priceH = 2 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[7].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0131){
      priceI = 3 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[8].c_str());
  }

  else if (code == 0132){
     priceJ = 4 * amount;
  printf("%s\n",product[9].c_str());
  }
  //} 

  int coupon = 0;
  //while (coupon != 000){
      cout << "Please enter your coupon code, if you do not have any, please press '0'. Press '000' when finished entering coupon(s)\n";



  cin >> coupon;

  if (coupon == 051){
      cout << "50% discount of 'Bounty Tissue'\n";

       priceB = priceB / 2;
  }
  else if (coupon == 017){
      cout << "$2 off any Hagen Daaz product\n";

       priceA = priceA - 2;
  }
  else if (coupon == 046){
      cout << "$1 off two Lays original Chips\n";

       priceE = priceE * 2 - 1;
  }
  else if (coupon == 035){
      cout << "$1 off any Sunny D product\n";

      priceF = priceF - 1;
  }

  else if (coupon == 0){
      cout << "Your purchase is being processed\n";
  }
  //}


  int bags = 0; 
  cout << "How many bags would you like to purchase(1 bag/$1 each)?\n";

  cin >> bags;

  bags = bags * 1;


  int subtotal = priceA + priceB + priceC + priceD + priceE + priceF + priceG + priceH + priceI + priceJ + bags;
  cout << "Subtotal:\n\n " << subtotal;
  double total = subtotal * 1.1;
  cout << "Total:\n\n " << total;

  int payment = 0;
  int pin = 0;
  double change = 0;
  double cash = 0;

  cout << "Would you like to pay with debit or cash? Press '1' for debit and '2' for cash\n";

  cin >> payment;


      if (payment == 1){
          cout << "Enter your pin number: ";
          cin >> pin;
          cout << "Approved. Your purchase is processing...\n";
      }
      else if (payment == 2){
          cout << "Please enter the amount you are paying with:\n";
          cin >> cash;
          change = cash - total;
      }

  cout << "Thank you for your purchase. Your reciept is printing...\n";
  cout << "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<SM Supermarket>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n";
  cout << " Cashier: Samantha & Madeleine\n";
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "--------------------------------------------------------\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[0].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceA << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[1].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceB << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[2].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceC << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[3].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceD << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[4].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceE << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[5].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceF << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[6].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceG << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[7].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceH << "\n" ;
  printf("%s\n",product[8].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceI << "\n";
  printf("%s\n",product[9].c_str());
  cout << "$" << priceJ << "\n";
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "Bags";
  cout << "$" << bags;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "-----------------";
  cout << "Subtotal: " << subtotal << "\n";
  cout << "Total: " << total << "\n";
  cout << "Amount Given: " << cash << "\n";
  cout << "Change: " << change << "\n";
  cout << "-----------------";
  cout << "Thanks for shopping at SM Supermarket!";
  cout << "***************************************";
  cout << "Please press '1' to exit. Have a nice day!";
  int exit = 0;
  cin >> exit;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen.  As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem.   (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: You'll want to watch those octal literals.

Comment: consider using a map instead of many else-if statements.

Comment: Nobody's going to wade through all that code. Start chopping things out. If the problem still occurs, chop some more. If the problem goes away, put back the last part that you chopped and chop something else. Repeat until you understand what's wrong, or you have a **much** smaller example to post here.